# Mapping a collection without an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is it possible in hibernate to map a collection of a value/column from entity B inside entity A without having the entity B itself?

So suppose Table B contains many fields/columns including this long field, lets just call it building_id. That's the only one I care about.

Inside A can I just have

```
List<Long> buildings;
```

Rather than

```
 @oneToMany
 List<B> buildings;
```

Where A has a primary key column corresponding to a foreign key in B, where for a given A there is many Bs (OneToMany). Hence, we get a list of building_ids inside A.

Comment: I don't think so. How would Hibernate know that Long corresponds to building_id in table B?

Comment: Possibly through the use of some annotations specifying the Table and columns and possibly a join? I mean, I don't mind creating the entity B, but I just don't need all the columns associated with it or even the overhead and extra space taken up by the Object (when I just need longs)

Comment: You can create an entity B with just B's primary key and building_id field mapped -- regardless how many other columns table B has, and do a `List<B> buildings`, however this is not "without an entity"

Comment: So you are suggesting at a minimum you need at least the primary keys of the entity mapped to an object?

Comment: Yes, otherwise when you merge the entity, how would hibernate know which row to update? Maybe you can get away not mapping primary key if reading only, but I don't know if this will cause Hibernate error

Comment: I was hoping on the load it could be read-only (since loads are more common than saves so it could be worth optimizing the memory there), and then when it came time to map it back and save I would translate these longs to the actual entity B and have hibernate save it. But looks like even that will not work if I can't get these to be read-only (I don't want to create a separate HQL query for this either)

Comment: Crate a database view with the relevant data from B. You can map this view to A as an ElementCollection.

Comment: @AlanHay Why do we need to create a database view? Why can't we directy map B's collection to A?